# SELECT random users from MySQL in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on optimizing a query

(select 2 random users from 1 table)

```
id  | name |  total | img
------------------------ --
1    user1   500      1
2    user2   600      2
3    user3   650      3
```

need result and ABS(total1 -total2) < 200

```
id1  | id2|  name1 | name2 | img1 | img2 |  total1 | total2
------------------------ -------------------------------------
1       3    user1   user3    1      3        500      650
```

for more performance rewrite this:

```
SELECT
  C1.id AS id1, C1.img AS img1, C1.name AS name1,
  C2.id AS id2, C2.img AS img2, C2.name AS name2,
  C1.total AS total1, C2.total AS total2
FROM users C1, users C2
WHERE C1.id <> C2.id 
  AND ABS(C1.total - C2.total) < 200
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

TO

```
$dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
$rs = $dbh->query(
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count'
 FROM users C1, users C2
 WHERE C1.id <> C2.id
   AND ABS(C1.total - C2.total) < 200");
$target = rand(0,$rs[0]['count']);
$rs = $dbh->query(
  "SELECT 
   C1.id AS id1, C1.img AS img1, C1.name AS name1,
   C2.id AS id2, C2.img AS img2, C2.name AS name2,
   C1.total AS total1, C2.total AS total2
  FROM users C1, users C2
  WHERE C1.id <> C2.id
   AND ABS(C1.total - C2.total) < 200
  LIMIT ?,1",
array($target));


foreach ($rs as $row) 
                    { 
                     print $row['name1']; 
                     }
```

return empry result, what I missed, connection to db is ok (another queries are working)

Comment: Why do want two records in single row? Can't you do that after pulling two random records?

Comment: (C1.total - C2.total) < 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
SELECT u1.id1, u2.id2, u1.name1, u2.name2, u1.total1, u2.total2, u1.img1, u2.img2 
FROM 
(
    SELECT u.id id1, u.name name1, u.total total1, u.img img1 
    FROM users u 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) u1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT u.id id2, u.name name2, u.total total2, u.img img2 
    FROM users u 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) u2
WHERE u1.id1 != u2.id2 AND ABS(u1.total1 - u2.total2) < 200
LIMIT 0,1;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02695/13)

Comment: perfect! from 3.5 to 0.01 sec

Answer (score 1):

To select two random records, I usually do a

```
// Whatever your query is
order by rand() 
limit 2
```

Then you can do whatever calculation you need out of these two random records.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `prepare()` and `execute()`:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
  "SELECT 
   C1.id AS id1, C1.img AS img1, C1.name AS name1,
   C2.id AS id2, C2.img AS img2, C2.name AS name2,
   C1.total AS total1, C2.total AS total2
  FROM users C1, users C2
  WHERE C1.id <> C2.id
   AND ABS(C1.total - C2.total) < 200
  LIMIT ?,1");
$stmt->execute(array($target));

$rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

How about a single query instead of two: with reduced `rand()` calculations

```
SELECT C1.id AS id1,
       C1.img AS img1,
       C1.name AS name1,
       C2.id AS id2,
       C2.img AS img2,
       C2.name AS name2,
       C1.total AS total1,
       C2.total AS total2
  FROM(select *, rand() randval from users) C1, users C2
  WHERE C1.id <> C2.id AND ABS(C1.total - C2.total) < 200
  ORDER BY C1.randval DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: have this query and its slow

Comment: What's the rate of inserts/deletes on this table `users`? And how many records in total?

Comment: have now only 400 records and 1-st query in my question work about 3 second. And if I will have 1000 fields .. indexes was created

Comment: how frequent are inserts/deletes on this table? Coz if you ask for a offset out of range in `LIMIT` you'll get no records.

Comment: inserts/deletes only for admin, rare

Comment: can you add time taken by MySQL to run those three queries for clarity. Take a random `$target` value.

Comment: you mean `prepare` and `execute` for placeholders?

Comment: Oh yeah, from `159600 = ((400 * 400) - 400)` times `rand()` usage. ;-)

Comment: look Rostyslav Rava answer, 0.00.. sec

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it. Modified my version a bit.